# Partitioning the sum of squares of a regression where Fourier coefficients are the regression coefficients

Tags: regression, time-series, spectral-analysis

Given a finite realization from a time series, we can represent the n observations by the trigonometric polynomial

[image]

[image]

Where does the equation (7.1.2) come from? what partitioning of the sum of squares is being used here?

Comment: Equation 7.1.2 looks like a simple consequence of the expression on the first page for $a_k$, which I suspect is due to an orthogonality relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square line three of the first page. This is the squared value of X explained by the coefficient a. Move 2/N to the left hand side.

The math is easier than the realization that cos and sin portions of the regression are linearly separate.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more on "the sum of squares removed by the regression of $X_t$ on $\cos w_k t$ is the regression coefficient multiplied by the sum of cross products". I feel like I am still missing something here.

Comment: As I am understanding this, just think about $R^2$.  The explained sum of squares from the cos part of the cycle is equation 7.1.2.